# Why can some runways only be used from one end?

Tags: runways

Is there any reason for why some runways can only be landed and taken off from one end and not the other, even though there aren't any obstructions (mountains, etc.) and apparently can be used from both ends?

Comment: Sometimes it’s simply regulations and agreements. Do you have any specific example in mind?

Comment: Related/example: [Why can't runway 18 at Frankfurt Airport accept takeoffs or landings in the opposite direction?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/20803/18733)

Comment: Noise abatement procedures is probably the most likely reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if there are no physical obstacles visible - the airspace structure can be somewhat more difficult and one runway direction might run into other reserved airspace. Or just go over noise-sensitive neighborhoods...

Comment: Besides airspace reserved for e.g. military purposes, it might also be take-off/landing paths to other runways.