# Are there any runways that aren't labeled reciprocally to each other?

Tags: runways

Runways are generally labeled by their magnetic azimuth between 01 and 36. This means that runways are normally labeled on each end with a number that is reciprocal to the other by 180 degrees.

Do any runways exist where the approach ends aren't labeled reciprocally to each other?

Comment: "Magnetic variation, however, can have a considerable impact near the poles." but it is of course the same at both ends, unless you want to count thousandths of one degree ;).  I'm not sure what you are asking since, as runways are straight, one end must be 180 degrees opposed to the other.

Comment: @Simon If you have a runway crossing the North pole, you would have to number both ends with 36 don't you? ;-)

Comment: On [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/18988/8730) there are some examples of runways that are only labeled at one end

Comment: Unless the runway crosses the pole as @DeltaLima says, there isn't going to be enough magnetic variation over the course of a 8000 foot runway to change the numbering. Even if the variation was enough to cause a single digit change, I doubt it would happen as the pilot wouldn't account for the variation change that close to the airport anyway. I've seen signs at some airports that warn about the variation or a disturbance as much as 10 degrees, but it didn't affect numbering.

Comment: "The pole" isn't an exact point, and there is a very large area of "magnetic unreliability" where you could have just about any reading....

Comment: does this count? http://www.endlessrunway-project.eu/

Comment: @Lnafziger: Well, runways are numbered with respect to _true_ north in the area of magnetic unreliability, so if that area happened to include the _geographical_ pole...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Elk City, ID](https://www.airnav.com/airport/S90) has runway 14/35 with about 30 degrees between reciprocal approach paths:
[image: photo of S90]

Comment: Elk City was the first one that popped into my head too! Of course, the physical runway surface is not actually labelled. Fun strip!

Answer (score -2):

No, but at airports with multiple, parallel runways they will use an adjacent runway heading.

Example: KATL, Hartsfield Jackson Intl, in Atlanta, GA, which has five east-west parallel runways designates them Runways 8L-26R, 8R-26L, 9L-27R, 9R-27R, and 10-28.